# R writing excel file with XLSX package taking a long time and error

Tags: r

The "mydata" data frame has 128,000 rows. When I write it to an xlsx file it just keep running and when I stop it I get the error:

```
write.xlsx(x = mydata, file = "myfile.xlsx",
           sheetName = "Sheet1", row.names = FALSE)





Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Do you know what this means?

Comment: If your goal is to simply read the data into Excel, then you can use `write.csv(x = mydata, file = "myfile.csv"`  Then, it can be easily imported into Excel.

Comment: I need the file to be xlsx not csv

Comment: It's not directly answering your question (I have no idea why you're getting this error message), but have you tried the function `WriteXLS` (in the same name package)? That's the one I use to create .xlsx files and it works well (my datasets don't have 128,000 rows, though). Might be worth a try.

Answer (score 9):

I advise you not to use those libraries (write.xlsx2 & write.xlsx), indeed both are suffering about data size and a lot of format construction.
The simplest way to write a dataframe (I suppose your original data is in a dataframe structure or it's possible to transform them to a dataframe) is using **writexl** library.
Here there is an example:

```
library(writexl)

df <- data.frame(name = c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria"),
                 age = c(23,41,32))

xlx_store_path <- "where do you want to store the .xlsx file"

write_xlsx(df, xlx_store_path)
```

Complete suorce here: https://datatofish.com/export-dataframe-to-excel-in-r/

Comment: I actually tested this library and it is pretty amazing how fast it was, it took 3-4 seconds to export 46k rows and 37 columns

Comment: agreed! I gotta mention that readxl is a great way to read xlsx as data.frames as well

Answer (score 5):

Look into `write.xlsx2()` as well.  According to the documentation for the `xlsx` package,

> Function write.xlsx2 uses addDataFrame which speeds up the execution compared to write.xlsx by
>   an order of magnitude for large spreadsheets (with more than 100,000 cells).

When I have written large (i.e., >100,000 rows) to .xslx files, I have had the same problems that you've had.  using `write.xlsx2()` has solved those problems.

A last resort may be to write to a .csv, open in Excel, and re-save as a .xlsx.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

**`write.xlsx` fails when your data size is large.** Use the following method instead:

```
library(xlsx)
myfile="my_excel_file_name.xlsx" #DO NOT USE SPACES, it will cause errors

wb = createWorkbook() #create a workbook object

mysheet = createSheet(wb, "Sheet1") #create a sheet and name it
addDataFrame(df1, sheet=mysheet, startColumn=1, row.names=FALSE) #add data to Sheet1

sheet = createSheet(wb, "Sheet2") #create another sheet
addDataFrame(df2, sheet=mysheet, startColumn=1, row.names=FALSE) #add data to Sheet2

#.... add as many sheets/data as you want ....

saveWorkbook(wb, myfile) #write to a physical Excel file here
```

The Excel file will be created in your default working directory. If you want to create the file in a specific directory, you can use a full address when defining `myfile` or set your working directory to where you want to export the files:

```
setwd("C:/R Files/Exported Files")
```

If by any chance it did not work, try to restart R by:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (PC)

or

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (Mac)

**UPDATE 1:**

I tested `writexl` suggested by `@Hamza` and its performance is really amazing compared to `xlsx` library that suffers a lot from memory problems whereas `writexl` is **fast and no Java or Excel required**. You can even write Excel formulas with this library from inside R.

Here is how you can simply write a large dataframe:

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(df, "C:/Users/my_user_name/Downloads/exported_from_r.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, add this line to your R script (or run it from console in RStudio).

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m")
```

I had a similar problem but the increase in this parameter for memory solved it.

After the comment to this, it can't hurt to reboot.  :)

Comment: That just kept running too

Comment: Sometimes it works to quit R and start again.  I know, pretty low-tech, but when I can't figure out the gremlins, I start clean and sometimes they disappear.  Also, as I reread your question, I realized that my problem was reading large Excel files, not writing them.  Not sure it matters.